# Is there a GLIBC version that includes glibc 2.0 and 2.17?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, dependencies, rhel-6, glibc

I am using RHEL 6.5. For some dependency issues, I need GLIBC 2.17. I successfully upgraded to 2.17 but the earlier versions like 2.0 are now gone and I need them too. Is there any version that would have both? Or a way to use two glibc versions together?

Below is the exact error I get with GLIBC 2.17. The error I received earlier was how 2.17 is missing. (Don't have an image of it to share right now)

> [root@Marium ~]# rpm -hiv compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.i686.rpm
> warning: compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.i686.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 >Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
> error: Failed dependencies:
> libc.so.6 is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.i686
> libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.i686
> libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.i686
> libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.i686
> libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.i686
> libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.i686
> libgcc_s.so.1 is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.i686
> libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.i686
> libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.3) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.i686
> libgcc_s.so.1(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.i686
> libm.so.6 is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.i686

Comment: Do you need just symbols from glibc 2.17, or do you actually need that exact version?  Please edit your question to tell us what you want to do specifically and any messages you're receiving.

Comment: @bk2204 I have made the edits.

Comment: Is it possible that you're mixing 32-bit and 64-bit binaries?

Comment: 32bit `libstdc++.so.5 > libstdc++.so.5.0.7` : Please use a later package : $ wget ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/www.mde.djura.org/pclinuxos/2004/RPMS.thac.exp/libstdc++5-3.3.6-2.pclo2005.mde.i586.rpm → `yum install ./libstdc++5-3.3.6-2.pclo2005.mde.i586.rpm` ... Installs also OK with glibc-2.33 !!

Comment: `compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.i686.rpm` also works OK (  ldd libstdc++.so.5.0.7 ) with glibc-2.33 .... so I guess you got a very limited version of the installed *glibc-2.17* .

Answer (score 1):

The package you're using is for RHEL 7 and it almost certainly isn't going to work on RHEL 6.  Unlike other distros such as Debian, where mixing packages between versions can sometimes work, that isn't the case for RHEL or CentOS, and things such as dependencies can change across versions incompatibly.

It's possible that you may be able to use a RHEL or CentOS 6 package that provides the same functionality, or you may need to upgrade your OS.

Additionally, RHEL 6.5 no longer receives security support, so it should not be used in a context where it is connected directly or indirectly to the Internet, since that permits it to be compromised and be a threat to other systems.